# Facing error on Maps API v3 Places Autocomplete Form

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am using `Maps API v3 Places Autocomplete form` last few month for my project but when I am adding to another page `Places Autocomplete` is not working.

I am getting error on this line:

```
for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = ''; 
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
}
```

and getting this error message: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Here is my autocomplete code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
    // to geographical location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        //types: ['geocode']
        types: ['geocode', 'establishment']
    });
    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
    // populate the address fields in the form.
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        fillInAddress();

    });

}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var formatted_address = place.formatted_address;

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation, geolocation));
        });
    }
}

initialize();
// [END region_geolocation]
});
</script>
```

My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/Ls2ag2p0/

Any Idea? Why it is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're getting the null pointer when it is attempting to assign the country. Try adding in field for the country, such as

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="" placeholder="" class="form-control" maxlength="15"/>
</div>
```

When I added that to the JSFiddle you submitted, it worked correctly.